# Add interface on this of the function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to add the type on **this** of the function  but I am not sure how I can do it

```
interface ThisFunction{
    test:Function
}
function exampleFunction(){
//I want to add type of this to be of interface of ThisFunction like 
//I know that I will always bind the Test instance this should have interface as ThisFunction 
this.test();
}
//When I call the function
exampleFunction().bind({test: ()=>null})
```

Comment: `function exampleFunction(this: TestClass)` https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/function-this-parameter.html

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calling an interface "...Class" though. That's confusing.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Thank for suggestion, I tried to  make  question more understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type `this` like that:

```
interface ThisFunction {
  test: Function
}

function exampleFunction(this: ThisFunction) {
  this.test();
}

const boundExampleFunction = exampleFunction.bind({ test: () => null })

boundExampleFunction()
```

This code is safe because TypeScript statically checks that `this` matches its declared type. For example it will throw an error if you try to call `exampleFunction` without binding it. However, you could inline the function declaration and the `bind` operation if you don't want to expose the unbound function as a variable:

```
interface ThisFunction {
  test: Function
}

const exampleFunction = (function (this: ThisFunction) {
  this.test();
}).bind({ test: () => null })

exampleFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

To type `this`, I think you could code it like that:

```
interface ThisFunction{
    test: Function
}
function exampleFunction(){
     const thing: ThisFunction = this
}
```